# He is respected every where but not at home.He is a --------------

Tags: single-word-requests, word-choice, word-usage

What  is a man who  is respected  outside  everywhere  but  is  not  liked  by  the  members  of  his  family.

X   is  respected  everywhere  but  he  is  not  respected  at home  ,   he  is  a --------------------

I would like  to  know  the  word  that  is  suitable  in the  blank.

Comment: There  are  many  great  people  who  are  respected  everywhere  except  at  home. Tolstoy is  a  good   example  of  this. Even  Mahatma  Gandhi  had  the  similar  fate.His  sons  hated  him.

Comment: https://biblehub.com/luke/4-24.htm shows many translations of the relevant Luke 2:24 verse.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The situation you describe is referred to in slightly different ways by the four evangelists as relating to Jesus being unappreciated where he was from.  It has become proverbial in many languages under a form meaning *Nemo propheta in patria sua*.  You could say:

> - X is respected everywhere but he is not respected at home, nobody is a prophet in their own land.

Comment: The most familiar English version is "A prophet is not without honour save [except] in his own country".(https://www.dictionary.com/browse/a-prophet-is-not-without-honor-save-in-his-own-country)

Comment: @KateBunting  Has the quote achieved proverbial status?  In my language, French, the expression is widely used outside of any religious context, to the point that most people are not aware any longer that it's taken from the Bible.  I wouldn't want to suggest an answer that has little currency in English.

Comment: If you scroll down the link I supplied, there's a reference to it as a proverbial saying. Like other sayings derived from the King James Bible, it's probably less widely known among the younger generation as education has become more secular.